# Why selenium trying to locate same element with previous ID

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have first page with one ID:

```
['schwarz', 'rosa']
id  = "schwarz"
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="d5e1e51e-620d-44c8-9508-d79aed865922", element="feb91d78-fc5a-44c6-90ba-0a233d97f8fd")>
```

I have second page with another ID:

```
['schwarz', 'rosa']
id = "rosa"
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="d5e1e51e-620d-44c8-9508-d79aed865922", element="ef190e76-c1c1-432a-8ee7-2ece61f71923")>
```

selenium works great on first page, but on next page I have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1\l.py", line 223, in <module>
    actions.move_to_element(colourinput).click().perform()
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py", line 80, in perform
    self.w3c_actions.perform()
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\actions\action_builder.py", line 76, in perform
    self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_ACTIONS, enc)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <input **id="schwarz"** class="product-variants__input" name="attributeSet" type="radio"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

Is it trying to use previous id? I'm erasing id *del id* before using next id but t doesn't work.

````
for i in range(len(coloursarray)):
                    del colourid
                    colourid = coloursarray[i]
                    if colourid != '':
                        colourinput = driver.find_element_by_id(colourid)
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        actions.move_to_element(colourinput).click().perform()```
````

Comment: Hi Nadya,  Can you please share your code so far?

Comment: can you please add that to your post? - press edit and place it in the code same tags (use the header bar at the top of the text field)  - it's difficult to read in the comments and it's useful to have it in the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what's in your colours array or seeing your application, it's most likely failing because your loop is moving fast then your application.

When you click your first object, consider what happens to the page. Does it go to a new page? Do scripts run which update the DOM? - You need to handle those situations.

Potentially, you need to instruct selenium to wait until the next element is ready before continuing.

It might work if you add....

These imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And use this loop:

```
for i in range(len(coloursarray)):
    del colourid
    colourid = coloursarray[i]
    if colourid != '':
        colourinput = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, colourid)))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        actions.move_to_element(colourinput).click().perform()
```

Note that i added a `webdriverwait` to your existing identification approach.

If this returns a timeout error then it's possible that that your second ID is not present in the DOM. However, you'll need to investigate further or share your URL in order for someone to help.

For more information on waits and other Expected Conditions, please see [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: I tried waiting using WebdriverWait I have timeout error ```"selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:"``` cause selenium stiil waiting for ID "black"(this is the problem) but on this page there is ID "rosa"

Comment: It finds first ID  perfect, but for the second ID selenium goes to the new page. The next page is absolutely new page not a updated DOM. After loading the new page which is fully loaded I have this error: ```The element reference of <input **id="schwarz"** class="product-variants__input" name="attributeSet" type="radio"> is stale;.. ```I see here selenium trying to reference to previous ID "schwarz" but should use next ID "rosa" .

Answer (score -1):

Actually I had to update *actions* every time after loading new page

actions = ActionChains(driver)